# Removing insignificant variables?

Tags: regression, feature-selection

Suppose you fit a linear regression model on some data with 10 variables. The *F*-statistic shows that 3 of them are significant (*p* < 0.05) , 2 are within trend (0.05 < *p* < 0.10), and the other 5 are *p* > 0.10. Is it OK to throw out the other 5 (*p* > 0.10) and retrain another model? Perhaps this time the 2 within trend will become significant.